# Cannot get ngAnimate to work in angular1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

This is my html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form role="form" ng-if="on" ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}">
...stuff...
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my model:

```
$scope.on = false;

//attaching this function to the window so i can call it from the console
window.switchOn = function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.on = !$scope.on
    });
}
```

This is my CSS:

```
.animate-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I've also added the `ngAnimate` inclusion to my app controller:

```
angular.module('app', [..., 'ngAnimate'])...
```

The purpose of this is to toggle the form from the console. According to the ngAnimate docs, the form should animate into appearance (I'm using Chrome). But it isn't. I've included the angular-animate file. I can see it in the loaded sources.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Step One**: Make sure you are including the `ng-animate` module.  Here are the steps from [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate):

> Animations are not available unless you include the [ngAnimate module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) as a dependency within your application.
>
> First include angular-animate.js in your HTML:

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular-animate.js">
```

> You can download this file from the following places:
>
> **Google CDN**
>
> ```
> //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-animate.js
> ```
>
> **Bower**
>
> ```
> bower install angular-animate@X.Y.Z
> ```
>
> **code.angularjs.org**
>
> ```
> //code.angularjs.org/X.Y.Z/angular-animate.js"
> ```
>
> where X.Y.Z is the AngularJS version you are running.
>
> Then load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module:
>
> ```
> angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
> ```
>
> With that you're ready to get started!

**Step Two:**
Your CSS needs to have a `.ng-enter` class:

```
.reveal-animation.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation: enter_sequence 1s linear; /* Safari/Chrome */
    animation: enter_sequence 1s linear; /* IE10+ and Future Browsers */
}
@-webkit-keyframes enter_sequence {
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes enter_sequence {
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
```

And your html simply has to have the class:

```
class="reveal-animation"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bpR66/

**If pre version 1.2**

Your CSS needs to have `-setup`, and `-setup.-start` classes:

```
.animate-enter-setup {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
    -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
    -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
    -o-transition:all linear 1s;
    transition:all linear 1s;
}

.animate-enter-setup {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity:0;
}
.animate-enter-setup.animate-enter-start {
    opacity:1;
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle I modified to show an example (not using a form, but should demonstrate): http://jsfiddle.net/xv5ry/1/

Comment: I've included the angular-animate file. I can see it in the loaded sources. Please see edit.

Comment: The element on the page does not have any ng-animate css classes. It looks like the ngAnimate directive is not being recognized by the app.

Comment: What do you mean? In the fiddle?  Or on your page?

Comment: Ahh, got it, my bad, didn't realize how much they had changed angular 1.2 animations, was using 1.1.4 to demonstrate.  See updated answer.

Comment: It looks like `.ng-enter` wasnt necessary... infact when i put it in the animation did not happen. Any thoughts on how to do a leave animation without `.ng-leave`?